# Session ID not working using PHP in Fedore 13 Goddard public server

Tags: php, mysql, session, fedora

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password = md5($_POST['pwd']);
            $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND pwd='".$password."'";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            $num=mysql_num_rows($result_set);
            if ($num > 0) 
            {
               $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);

                $_SESSION['uid'] = $found_user['id'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];
                     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
                location.reload();
                </script>";

            }
            else
            {
            header("location:login-register.php?error=1");
            }

        }
```

I am running this script inside my login page. It works perfectly in xampp localhost server but session id fails to load and work when I uploaded my folder to web-server which is using Fedora 13 with php version 5.3.5.

I have checked PHPinfo, session id is active but it is not working in the server. Please help.

Comment: fedora 13 is years after EOL. You should update to current version (23).

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start()` to the first line of php file.

```
 session_start();    
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['pwd']);
        $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND pwd='".$password."'";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result_set);
        if ($num > 0) 
        {
           $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
            location.reload();
            </script>";

        }
        else
        {
        header("location:login-register.php?error=1");
        }
```

Comment: thank you .. !! Is this is for web-servers or hosting server ? .. Because it doesn't show any error in local server (xampp/localhost).

Comment: if you have not yet add `session_start()` you cannot use session in PHP both local and server http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Yes, I have added session_start(); in config.php file.                               <?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpwd = "";
$dbase = "hcvdb3";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpwd);
mysql_select_db($dbase, $conn);
?>    and in every page i am calling this script "include("js/config.php");"  So now what is the problem, why it is not running in webserver, but running in local server ..

Comment: you maybe try add ob_clean() before session_start();

Comment: sorry, this is also not working .. I tried to put this in individual pages and also in config file where my session_start(); is running.

Comment: thank you, I have solved the problem. path problem is there as session folder is not created.. it's running gud now . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add `session_start()` at the top of the file in order to use `session`

> Side note :
>
> 1) Please dont use `mysql_`. It is deprecated and removed
>   from PHP 7.Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
>
> 2) Your query is open for sql injection. Read this :
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thank you .. !! Is this is for web-servers or hosting server ? .. Because it doesn't show any error in local server (xampp/localhost).

Comment: Session is not server specific. You have to use `session_start()` at the top of the file.

Comment: Yes, I have added session_start(); in config.php file.                               <?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpwd = "";
$dbase = "hcvdb3";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpwd);
mysql_select_db($dbase, $conn);
?>    and in every page i am calling this script "include("js/config.php");"  So now what is the problem, why it is not running in webserver, but running in local server ..

Comment: Just add `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domainname.com');` before your `session_start()` and replace `domainname.com with your domain name

Comment: sorry, this is also not working .. I tried to put this in individual pages and also in config file where my session_start(); is running.

Comment: Did your provide `.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME`?

Comment: Yes sir, I provided our domain name.

Comment: thank you, I have solved the problem. path problem is there as session folder is not created.. it's running gud now . thanks